# Why can we assume there is no charge in the derivation of dispersion relations (Drude theory)?

Tags: electromagnetism, solid-state-physics

In a derivation done by Ashcroft and Mermin (I am now doing the derivation for helicon waves as predicted by the Drude model), the authors use in deriving the condition for propagation of electromagnetic waves in a Drude metal (i.e. arriving at the notion of plasma frequency) that there is no charge so that Gauss's Law takes the form
$$\nabla \cdot \textbf{E} = 0.
$$ Why is it that they do this? Is this an assumption saying that *if* there is no charge, *then* we obtain said results?

I had also thought that maybe they made an argument that charge neutrality should be maintained everywhere for reasonably low frequencies, but I am not sure.

Comment: Metals are conductors, and low frequencies. Well, do not pay too much attention to Drude. Soon you will be learning much better understanding of solids.

Comment: Absolutely, but I just want to understand *why* we can make this assumption in *using* the Drude model. If I take your point, you are saying that because the dielectric relaxation time $\sigma/\epsilon$ is so small in metals we can take no bulk charge (as long as the inverse of the frequency of our light does not get close to this small)? @naturallyInconsistent

Comment: I am not particularly sure, but it is very typical that when we are trying to derive electromagnetic waves in anything, we would try to find the homogeneous, source-less part, because that is what the wave part solves. It is the standard separation of concerns that we would do to any linear system in physics.